# Source not found on AsyncTask.execute()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to get along with AsyncTask..
what my problem was that i was building a table of textviews dynamically, based on the output of a procedure.. But then i figured that by using asynctask i can do it in a more efficient way..So, what i did is as follows:

```
private class DisplayReport extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        //Message -- "Please wait while the Report Loads..."
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Here i fetch the data from the procedure via a web service
        //parse the result of web service and set a bool variable true or false based on whether the dataset fetched is empty or not.
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean value){
        if(value == true){
                 "Please try again later!!"
        }
        else{
                 runOnUiThread(GenTable);
        }
    }
    private Runnable GenTable = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                displayReport(result); // in this method i build the table.
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ad.setTitle("Error..");
                ad.setMessage(e.toString());
            }
        }
    };
}
```

the above async class is an inner class in my main class which extends activity.
and this is how i am executing the asynctask..

```
DisplayReport dr = new DisplayReport();
dr.execute();
```

now when i debug, i get the `"source not found" error on dr.execute()..`
i tried searching a lot on the net, but i simply cannot find out anything concrete. Also, please let me know if my approach is incorrect..
this question might seem very silly, but i am new to android and java as well and any help would be really great..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Execute is going to start a new thread.  You don't want to debug into it.  Instead, put breakpoints in onPreExecute, doInBackground, and onPostExecute and you can see when each of those gets called.

Comment: Also, onPostExecute is always run on the UI thread, so you don't need to call runOnUiThread there.  Only doInBackground is run on the other thread.

Answer (score 0):

`onPostExecute` is already being run in the UI thread, so you should not create another runnable for it. Just make your `onPostExecute` like this:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Boolean value){
            if(value == true){
                     String message = "Please try again later!!";
                     // Do something here with your message
            }
            else{
                     displayReport(result);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try and get back if i have some more problems :)

Comment: i guess even the doInBackground is also not getting executed.. i fire a query in it and its not getting reflected in the sql profiler..