# Getting rid of the black screen

Tags: android, android-gui

This question has probably been asked a lot many times.. Yes! I am facing the so called "black screen problem"..
My first activity is which the main activity, in which login is done, and  this activity is followed by the next one which is a simple summary report of the user's account.
Now, for this report, i fetch the dataset, parse it and use it to build the table dynamically.
The villan black screen appears here!! The report, as in the table is rendered properly, but upon that screen, this black tranluscent layer keeps appearing.
I tried everything, using handlers, asynctask, translucent theme but nothing helps!! The villan still appears when my summary report loads. It goes away if i press the "Back" button, and the screen appears normal, as it is expected to be when it loads the first time.. I cant figure out what exactly is going wrong, whether, its my coding approach(dynamically generating the table) or it is an emulator problem or what.

`My emulator details are as follows:`
`CPU:ARM`
`Target: Android 2.3.3`
`skin: WVGA800`
`sd card:1024M`

Someone please rescue me!!

**EDIT:**
In my Second activity i do the following:

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_summary_report);
        ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        boolean is = IsConnectedToNetwork(); 
        if (is == true){
                Handler execWS = new Handler();
                execWS.post(callWS);//Fetch Data via web service and parse it
                if(result != null){
                    Handler genUI = new Handler();
                    genUI.post(createUI);// generate the table based on "result". ie. in a for loop i create textviews and append it to the table layout
                }
            }
        else{
            Error = "Connection Failed. Try Again!";
        }
        if(Error.length() != 0){
        ad.setMessage(Error);
        ad.setTitle("Error..");
            ad.show();
        }
    }
```

My Xml layout for the second activity..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:contentDescription="@string/Logo"
                android:src="@drawable/complogo" 
                android:gravity="top"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblLoginInfo"  
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    </TableLayout>


    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tblSummRep"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:padding="5dip">
    </TableLayout>
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dip">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/AppName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/AppName"
                android:textColor="#ff6600" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/AppVersion"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/AppVersion"
                android:textColor="#ff6600" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Disclaimer"
                        android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Disclaimer"                   
                android:textColor="#ff6600" />
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I append the textview to "tblSummRep"..

**UPDATE**
my asynctask class..

```
   private class ShareWork extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{
        ProgressDialog pDlg;
        //String[][] result = null;
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            pDlg.setMessage("Please wait while the Report Loads...");
            pDlg.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            boolean RetVal = false;
            //my fetch code
            return RetVal;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean value){
            if(value == true){
                pDlg.setMessage("Please try again later!!");
                pDlg.show();
            }
            else{
                createUI.run();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can we see some code..???

Comment: also can you post the screen shot?

Comment: And while you are at it, I suggest you reformat your question. As it is it is pretty hard to read it and some people will just skip it because of that.

Comment: Post your xml layout code

Comment: @Audrius point noted, i hope its readable now..

Comment: @Amruta show some code or if possible upload screenshot

Comment: @SilentKiller I have added, please refer the edit..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know what do you refer to by "black screen problem", but you state that you are fetching data (I guess from a remote server) and that happens. That sounds to me about blocking the UI thread. In which method of the activity are you fetching the data (maybe in the onCreate)? You should not perform time-consuming actions on the graphical thread, such as querying a remote server (which could take some seconds). In these cases always an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) should be used.  The user should receive some feedback about what is going on in the background, so using a ProgressBar is normally recommendable (or at least a spinner).

You can take a look about how to solve a similar problem with an AsyncTask [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7713264/34880).

**Update**

You have just posted your code. The problem lies (as I presumed) in this line of code:

```
execWS.post(callWS);//Fetch Data via web service and parse it
```

I guess this is a WS call. You are blocking here the UI thread. Create an AsyncTask the same way as the one of the link I provided, and upon completion of the task execute the rest of the code (display error or the dynamic table with the data).

Your AsyncTask could look like this (I have not tried it):

```
private class LoadTableTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Object> {
     protected Object doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         Handler execWS = new Handler();
         execWS.post(urls[0]);//Fetch Data via web service and parse it
         return result;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         //Not used in your case. It would be a good idea to create an undefined progress dialog in your case
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
         if(result != null){
                Handler genUI = new Handler();
                genUI.post(createUI);// generate the table based on "result". ie. in a   for loop i create textviews and append it to the table layout
         }

     }
 }
```

Your onCreate() method would be replaced by:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_summary_report);
    ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    boolean is = IsConnectedToNetwork(); 
    if (is == true){
            new LoadTableTask().execute(callWS);
        }
    else{
        Error = "Connection Failed. Try Again!";
    }
    if(Error.length() != 0){
    ad.setMessage(Error);
    ad.setTitle("Error..");
        ad.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i am fetching the data from a remote server, I am not performing the fetch on the main thread. I also tried using the async task. But somehow i am not able to get rid of that black layer that appears on the screen, which i am refering as the "Black screen problem" :)

Comment: Thanks, I have alreay tried it.. Check my update.. i have added the asynctask class..That gave error of source not found.. and then later i switched to handler.. [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393800/source-not-found-on-asynctask-execute) that question

Comment: pDlg is null. Create it on onPreExecute(). You should not reuse the progressdialog in the onPostExecute(). Instead of that dismiss the previous one and show an alert modal window, not a progress dialog (since you want to display an error message).

Comment: hey, i am trying what u have suggested. I am not getting anywhere, there seems to be a problem in doINbackground :(  I'll do some more investigation about what i am doing wrong. Thanks for your help. I'll get back to you if i need some more guidance. Thanks again! :)

Comment: There was a realy minor mistake i did which went unnoticed! i was trying to access a GUI element in doinbackground.. Thanks a looot for your help!!